# Change the default path where the web server looks for images

Tags: php, directory, default, chdir

I'm trying to change the default path or add a path that the webserver looks for images. I really would really like a solution to do this in PHP and not in htaccess.

The most basic example would be trying to "break" the current implementation so say I have a directory with the following:

**main/**

- image.png
- index.php

In `index.php`:

```
<?php
// Change the directory WAY out of current directory
chdir('../../../');
echo getcwd(); // DEFINITELY NOT where image.png is located

?>

<img src="image.png" width="402" height="265" alt="1">
<!-- WHY ARE YOU STILL RENDERING?!?! -->
```

Let me know if you understand my point or if you have any questions.

Thanks all!
Matt Mueller

Comment: lol. it's rendering because you have changed path in PHP, not browser :)

Comment: I figured they were different haha.. Man.. tell me there is something I can do about this..

Comment: About what? Ask a sensible question first. I see no point in making image unable to load

Comment: @jnpcl it will affect not only images

Comment: @jnpcl The `<base>` element `href` attribute requires an absolute URI, eg `http://example.com/base/path/`

Comment: it was more of a joke than a suggestion. :)

Comment: No need to get nasty @Col. Shrapnel, this is a simplified version of my problem that makes more sense than trying to explain my exact issue. Thanks @jnpcl, but I'm looking for a page-wide solution.

Comment: I am not getting nasty. I am merely trying to explain that asking senseless questions is not the way to go. There are can be many solutions, depends on your real problem. Put some effort in formulating your real issue. If you can't explain it even to yourself, that means you don't quite understand what are you doing. Asking questions in that case would be a waste of time. No offense, it's just usual way of doing things, isn't it? Note that you have messed up a webserver and a browser. That means your knowledge is not so strong. That's another reason to ask not a dummy question but a real one.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing the current working directory on the server filesystem and the web server document root.

When you create an image element in HTML, it (the browser) looks for the source based on a few parameters.

1. If the src path is relative (no leading slash), the image will load relative to the `<base>` element URL if set, otherwise the current URI
2. If the src path is absolute, the image will load from the absolute path from the document root, eg `<img src="/foo/bar/baz.jpg">` will load from http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.jpg
3. If the src is an absolute URI, then it will simply load from that

Comment: Oh interesting. Can you just quick explain what the difference between number 2 & 3?

Comment: @Matt Absolute URI is `http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/baz.jpg` where Absolute path is `/foo/bar/baz.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

The img tag is sent to the **client**.
changing the directory of the preprocessor will not change the client's directory, as that is fixed to the current page they are on, such as http://example.com/.

You would need to change each img tag's src to change the directory to look in.

To avoid future confusion, you could have a function that prefixes the correct directory.

e.g.

```
<img src = "<?php echo produceImageURL('image.png'); ?>" width = "402" height = "265" alt = "1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the relative path for PHP and the relative path for the page are two separate things.

You changed the directory for the current PHP script. However, the requested page and it's resources are still relative to `main/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

jnpcl had it right:

```
<base href="../../../">
```

put that between your `<head> </head>` typically after `<meta />`, before you load any files