# relative path in javascript external file

Tags: javascript, url, relative-path

I am trying to make this picture showing but I had no success.

If I do

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="../images/blockUI_Loader.gif" />';
```

I get from fiddler

[image]

If I do

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="../_assets/images/blockUI_Loader.gif" />';
```

I get from fiddler

[image]

If I use

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="~/_assets/images/blockUI_Loader.gif" />';
```

I get from fiddler

[image]

My folder structure is as follow

[image]

the js file is in the `js` folder.

Comment: Travis unfortunately did not accepted to be wrong...It deleted his answer and then came here to downvote...oh Travis Travis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution is to apply classes to your elements via JavaScript and set a background image using CSS.

Relative `url` paths in CSS are always relative to the stylesheet file which can make them easier to keep consistent.

For example

Javascript

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<div class="blockUI-Loader"></div>';
```

CSS

```
.blockUI-Loader {
    /* url path is relative to this CSS file in "_assets/css" */
    background-image: url(../images/blockUI_Loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: nnpx; /* width of image */
    height: nnpx; /* height of image */
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that url paths are relative to the css while @Amir Raminfar is saying that they are relative to the HTML... who's wrong? :)

Comment: Read my answer again. Relative paths in JavaScript are relative to the calling URI (the page). Relative paths in CSS files are relative to the CSS file location.

Comment: @Phil Brown: sorry! I've missed the CSS text.

Comment: @Phil Brown; I have done a new trial using `"../../_assets/images/blockUI_Loader.gif"` that is relative to the  Master Page from which all the pages inherits. Anyway the result is the same :(

Comment: The location of your Master page has nothing to do with your CSS. Anyway, I've added an example.

Comment: @Philip Brown: Yes! That would work for sure also! Thanks for posting the code. I will probably try to change the actual found solution (look at end of the page) with yours as it is more consistent IMO. I hav eto do some trials if it is accepted from the blockUI jquery plugin. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The relative path is relative to the HTML file and not the js file. So looking above at your other files, I am guessing you need to images/...

Comment: I changed it to images/ because it should be relative to the html file.

Comment: HTML file? That code is inside a javascript function that is used from almost all my mvc views...

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. You are making your images relative to the JS file. But it has nothing to do where the js file is. It is relative to where the HTML file is because that is where it is being rendered. If you using it many places then you might want to set a global like  base = "/xyz"; and then use base everywhere in you javascript file

Comment: Where are you including the javascript file?

Comment: Guys, he's using .NET. This is a web application, not a web "site".

Comment: It's relative to what the browser sees as a file. If you are using routing, each level of `/parameter/parameter` looks like a folder to the browser. If you have variable numbers of path parts in your URLs, you cannot use path-relative URLs at all because each page will be at a different level relative to the target. In that case you must use rooted URLs, constructing home-relative URLs as necessary on ASP.NET.

Comment: @Travis: Right. It is an ASP.NET MVC web application

Comment: @bobince: wait wait... that instruction is simply a tag the the jquery blockUI plugin will render at runtime on the page. It is not an url that will be routed

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the soultion!

```
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="_assets/images/blockUI_Loader.gif" />';
```

Comment: why? All my pages are in subdirectory and it is working well even if the page is in a directory two levels deep...

Comment: Given that it's an MVC application, the request URL could look like `controller`, `controller/action`, `controller/action/id` (given the default routing scheme). Each of these changes the base URI for the request and thus, any relative path requests. For example, the first will look for your image in `_assets/images`, the second in `controller/_assets/images` and the third in `controller/action/_assets/images`

Comment: Yes. So my pages are located, from the project root, to the `\Views\ViewName` folder. For example it is workin gon my home page that is located in the folder `\Views\Home\Index.aspx`

Comment: Your views are not the requested page though. See my edit above

Comment: I think you are confusing Controller and Action with Views. Every Views in an MVC project resides in a folder that has the name of the Controller (e.g. Home) inside a root folder called "Views". When an action try to render a view the View Engine will look for the view inside the folder structure that I have just described.

Comment: Please have a look to this SO question for more details `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735240/change-the-views-location`

Comment: @Lorenzo You are confusing the files on your server (classes, views, etc) with HTTP. Requests are made to your application and it responds with content. Relative paths in that content are resolved using the **URI** used to make the initial request or a **URI** set in a `<base>` tag in the returned HTML. This will look something like `hostname.com/xyz/controller/action`

Comment: I am not confusing You-re right on this. But the same rule does not apply to views. Views are rendered inside an action method that has been routed, after an http request, through a route. The action select an ActionResult to send back to the client. That result is a View. To do this, it simply select a view from disk not from another http request that would be unuseful. Look at this article `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123.aspx`

Comment: Sorry Philip. Do you agree that you dont call a view in an url of an MVC project? If you agree on this you ca understand that the view does pass through a route and it is part of an HTTP response not an HTTP Request

Comment: @Lorenzo The physical location on disk for your view scripts (including Master pages) has nothing to do with how the client (browser) resolves relative paths in the returned HTML. Only the content rendered from your view is part of the response. **No** other information about the view script including its name and path on disk is sent back to the client. The only location information the client knows is that used to make the request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029091/change-the-default-path-where-the-web-server-looks-for-images/4029121#4029121

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing in two different manner :)